# Java: Rolling two dice until you get a desired sum

Tags: java, dice

I want to write a program where I roll two die, until I get the sum of those dice being 11. I want to record how many "attempts" or rolls of the dice I used by the time I got the sum of 11.

My code so far:

```
public class Dice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int counter1 = 0; //Amount of rolls player 1 took to get sum of 9
    int P1sum = 0;

    do {
        int P1Die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
        int P1Die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;  
        P1sum = (P1Die1 + P1Die2);
        counter1++;
    } while (P1sum == 11);

        System.out.println("Player 1 took "+counter1+" amount of rolls to have a sum of 11.");  
    }
}
```

It just keeps printing that it took 1 roll to get a sum of 11, so something's not right.

My goal: Have player 1 keep rolling 2 die until I get a sum of 11, and record how many tries it took. Then have player 2 do the same. Then whichever player has the lower amount of tries "wins" the game.

Help appreciated thanks im a newbie

Comment: Your condition is wrong, it should be `while (P1sum != 11)` instead of `while (P1sum == 11)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to update your condition

```
while (P1sum == 11) // this results in false and exit anytime your sum is not 11
```

to

```
while (P1sum != 11) // this would execute the loop until your sum is 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider, that `Math.random()` returns floating point number *`0 <= x <= 1.0`* ([Java API docs Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--)). So, the maximum value of your formula:

```
(int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
```

equals to 7.